# Checking either the table in Access database is exist or not

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I want to check if the table in Access Database Exist or not
How can i do that ?
I tried this SQL Statement but it returns error

```
string SQLSTatement = @"SELECT * as Exists from MsysObjects WHERE type = 1 AND name = 'Table_Name'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `select * as 'label'`, just use a column name or a expresion

```
string SQLSTatement = @"SELECT name as 'Exists' from MsysObjects WHERE type = 1 AND name = 'Table_Name'"
```